# spring-rabbit JSON deserialization for ArrayList contents

Tags: json, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am using Spring-boot with rabbitmq with JSON message serialization.  Replies using the Direct-Reply-to feature cannot deserialize my classes inside the `java.util.List` container.

Using my debugger in `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter.fromMessage()`,  the `MessageProperties` states the `__TypeID__` is correctly set to `java.util.ArrayList`.  However the `__ContentTypeId__` is `java.lang.Object` is incorrect as I would be expecting FooDto (I assume...).
The exception message is:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to FooDto`

Please note, I am using spring-rabbit 1.7.3 and not v2.0 so cannot use the `ParameterizedTypeReference` for `rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceiveAsType()` method.

I have attempted to use the `DefaultClassMapper` and the `DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper` (with TypePrecedence tested under both `TYPE_ID` and `INFERRED`) without success:

```
private DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper classMapper() {
    final DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper classMapper = new DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper();
    final Map<String, Class<?>> idClassMapping = new HashMap<>();
    idClassMapping.put(FooDto.class.getSimpleName(), FooDto.class);
    classMapper.setIdClassMapping(idClassMapping);
return classMapper;
}
```

The exception is now:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to FooDto`

My workaround so far has been to use arrays of the raw types i.e. `FooDto[]`.

**Library versions:**
- spring-boot 1.5.6
- RabbitMQ: 3.7.4
- spring-rabbit 1.7.3

**Maven pom.xml:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
</dependencies>
```

**Effective Pom:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**RabbitMQ configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class MessagingConfiguration implements ShutdownListener {

    // FIXME: List<FooDto> in the direct-reply response contains  ArrayList<Object> due to __ContentTypeID__ == SimpleObject/Object .  __TypeID__ is correctly ArrayList

    @Bean
    public List<Declarable> bindings() {
    final List<Declarable> declarations = new ArrayList<>();
        final FanoutExchange exchange = new FanoutExchange("fx", true, false);
        final Queue queue = QueueBuilder.durable("orders").build();
        declarations.add(exchange);
        declarations.add(queue);
        declarations.add(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange));
        return declarations;
    }

    // @Bean
    // public DefaultClassMapper classMapper() {
    // DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
    // Map<String, Class<?>> idClassMapping = new HashMap<>();
    // idClassMapping.put("FooDto", FooDto.class);
    // java.util.List<FooDto>
    // classMapper.setIdClassMapping(idClassMapping);
    // return classMapper;
    // }
    //
    // @Bean
    // public DefaultClassMapper classMapper() {
    // final DefaultClassMapper typeMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
    // // typeMapper.setDefaultType(new ArrayList<FooDto>().getClass());
    // typeMapper.setDefaultType(FooDto[].class);
    // return typeMapper;
    // }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonConverter() {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491628/jackson-configuration-to-consume-list-of-records-in-rabbitmq
        // https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/295
        final Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        converter.setTypePrecedence(TypePrecedence.TYPE_ID);
        // converter.setClassMapper(classMapper());
        return converter;
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "consumer", havingValue = "true")
    @Bean
    public ConsumerListener listenerConsumer() {
        return new ConsumerListener();
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "producer", havingValue = "true")
    @Bean
    public ProducerListener listenerProducer() {
        return new ProducerListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin(final CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(
            final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        // Setting the annotation @RabbitListener to use Jackson2JsonMessageConverter
        final SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(jsonConverter());
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(5);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(5);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonConverter()); // convert all sent messages to JSON
        rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3));
        rabbitTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3));
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdownCompleted(final ShutdownSignalException arg0) {
    }
}
```

**The Listener consuming messages containing MyQuery objects from queue "orders" on exchange "fx":**

```
public class ConsumerListener {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumerListener.class);

    @RabbitListener(queues = { "orders" })
    public FooDto[] receiveMessage(final MyQuery query) {
        log.info(query);
        List<FooDto> response = new ArrayList<>();
        response.add(new FooDto());
        response.add(new FooDto());
        response.add(new FooDto());
        return response;
    }
}
```

**POJO used when sending a message to the Exchange:**
    class MyQuery {
        private String content = "test";

```
    public MyQuery();

    public String toString() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

**POJO used for the response:**
    class FooDto {
        private String content = "foo";

```
    public FooDto();

    public String toString() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something weird about your listener; it has a return type of `void` but you return a list.

That said, I think the problem is due to type erasure.

A custom `ClassMapper` won't help because that's just for a top-level class.

You should, however, be able to construct a custom [Jackson2JavaTypeMapper](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-amqp/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/support/converter/Jackson2JavaTypeMapper.java) to create a more complex type. The type mapper is consulted if there is not a class mapper. [See here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-amqp/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/support/converter/Jackson2JsonMessageConverter.java#L183).

I am not at a computer right now, but I can take a look tomorrow if you can't figure it out.

**EDIT**

Here's an example of how to customize the converter...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So49566278Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So49566278Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        template.setReplyTimeout(60_000);
        return args -> {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Foo> reply = (List<Foo>) template.convertSendAndReceive("so49566278", "baz");
            System.out.println(reply);
            Foo foo = reply.get(0);
            System.out.println(foo);
        };
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "so49566278")
    public List<Foo> handle(String in) {
        return Collections.singletonList(new Foo(in));
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("so49566278", false, false, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter converter() {
        Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        converter.setJavaTypeMapper(new DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper() {

            @Override
            public JavaType toJavaType(MessageProperties properties) {
                JavaType javaType = super.toJavaType(properties);
                if (javaType instanceof CollectionLikeType) {
                    return TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
                            .constructCollectionLikeType(List.class, Foo.class);
                }
                else {
                    return javaType;
                }
            }

        });
        return converter;
    }

    public static class Foo {

        private String bar;

        public Foo() {
            super();
        }

        public Foo(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        public String getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

        public void setBar(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo [bar=" + this.bar + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I edited my answer with an example of how to customize the type mapper.

Comment: I opened [AMQP-807](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-807) to fix this.

Comment: My ConsumerListener's return type was a bad edit for posting here. Sorry for the confusion.  Code updated here to what it actually is.

Many thanks for your code sample.  It worked!   I look forward to the resolution of AMQP-807 for the generic fix.

Comment: @GaryRussell is there a way to set converter through spring boot properties?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in a comment. It doesn't help people find answers. Always ask a new question. No, it must be a bean and boot will wire it in.

Comment: Doesn't this lock you in to only sending a `List` of `Foo`? Can we make the child content type dynamic?

Comment: You can add type information in a header in the reply message and adjust the type accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This way works with Collections without problems. I think it is very simple: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67130566/10746857